# How to duplicate and add more repeated contents to multiple selected rows with Excel VB?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to duplicate selected rows (first columns in picture) to get result as data like second and third column below.  I tried to use macro but sometimes there are >2000 rows. Please help me

http://i45.tinypic.com/2pph3cg.png

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A9"), Type:=xlFillCopy
ActiveCell.Range("A1:A9").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A9"), Type:=xlFillCopy
ActiveCell.Range("A1:A9").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "100"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "200"
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1:A2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A9")
ActiveCell.Range("A1:A9").Select
```

===========
In the code, I add 9 repeated rows not 300. (100,200,..900)

1. It moves(offsets) selected row by 1
2. It adds 9 rows
3. It moves back selected row by 1 (-1)
4. Then it starts to fill the value 100,200,... of cell A1:A9, because I used relative reference the cell range will change according to active cell

My try:

```
I do not know how to change the reference A1:A3 to relative one
```

They should be change accordingly when the active cell change.

```
Sub AddDuplicate()
```

'
'
I do not know how to change the reference A1:A3 to relative one 
They should be change accordingly when the active cell change.

My try
http://i49.tinypic.com/2mwxs39.png

Comment: It's an easy code. However show us the code that you recorded and explain your understanding of the code :) We will take it from there :)

Comment: It added my explanation according to my best understanding.

Comment: Why are you filling values 100, 200 etc? You snapshot shows something else?

Comment: It is just an example, I want to simplify the question.  The real one is to fill out with 100, 200, 300, ..900 instead of A, B, C

Comment: Ok here is the logic that you should follow. Since you are repeating each value from the 1st column 3 times then use a loop to loop though all the items in Col A and write to the relevant column and in the end write "A","B","C" to the first 3 rows and then use Autofill? I have already written the code. Maybe you would like to try it before I post the code? :)

Comment: For some reason, I cannot use the code style for this so I capture the image http://i49.tinypic.com/2mwxs39.png - thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least you tried :) And that is what I wanted to see :) Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim NewRow As Long, j As Long

    '~~> Name of the sheet where the the data lies
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        '~~> Get the last Row in Col A
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Row from where we need to write
        NewRow = 1

        '~~> Loop though each item in Col A
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            '~~> Write to Col C; 3 rows at a time
            .Range("C" & NewRow & ":C" & NewRow + 2).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value

            '~~> Get the next empty row
            NewRow = NewRow + 3
        Next

        '~~> Type "A","B","C" in Col D
        .Range("D1").Value = "A": .Range("D2").Value = "B": .Range("D3").Value = "C"

        '~~> Autofill till the last row
        .Range("D1:D3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D1:D" & NewRow - 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I need thank you very much.  Imagine I have to do this for multiple thousand rows - I much appreciate.

Comment: Just quick question - how do it stop the AutoFill to doing is automatic increment if I use numbers (A1,A2,A3) instead of letter (A,B,C).  For example if I used A1,A2,A3 then it will got to A4,A5,A6,A7,...

Comment: In that case do not use Autofill :) Write to the cells in the For loop.